# Can img tag show rezised image realtime from canvas image generated randomly by variable?

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie. I have a canvas which show a image from array by a button, another div/img tag will show that image with smaller size. When that button is pressed, image canvas change and image at div/img tag change too. What should I do?

Here is the code:

```
HTML:
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas><!--600x800-->
<input type="button" id="changeimg" value= "Change" onclick="ChangeImg();"></input>
<img src="imgs/1.jpg" height="230" width="300"></img>
```

JS:

```
var vCanvas;
var vStage;
vImg = new Image();
function init(){
    vImg.addEventListener('load',onImage,false);
    vImg.src = "imgs/1.jpg";
}
function onImage(e){
    setCanvas();
}
function setCanvas(){
    vCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    vStage = vCanvas.getContext('2d');
    vStage.drawImage(vImg, 0, 0, 800, 600, 0, 0, 800, 600);
}
function ChangeImg(){
    var Imgrs= new Array("imgs/1.jpg", "imgs/2.jpg", "imgs/3.jpg");
        vImg.src = Imgrs[Math.floor(Math.random() * Imgrs.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way would be to have another canvas and `drawImage` your first canvas into it (canvas counts as a valid image for drawImage).

If keeping an `<img>` tag is a requirement, you could do `image.src = canvas.toDataURL()` when updating the canvas contents (less recommended if updates happen in real-time).

Comment: Thank you! I got problem with 2 canvas. I mean, no more controls with img or div, it's only show that smaller img. I am not yet understand clearly .toDataURL()
Then I edited var vImgrs at ChangeImg() and used img tag with .setAttribute() --> document.getElementById('imgView').setAttribute('src', vImg.src); with this way, I can show the name/title of image as an introduction.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I did it!!
I was edited somethings:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="imgMain"></canvas><!--600x800-->
<input type="button" id="changeimg" value= "Change" onclick="ChangeImg();"></input>
<img id="imgView" height="230" width="300"/><h3 id="imgTitle"></h3>
```

JS at ChangeImg() and setCanvas() function:

```
function setCanvas(){
    vCanvas = document.getElementById('imgMain');
    vStage = vCanvas.getContext('2d');
    vCanvas.width = vPuzzleWidth;
    vCanvas.height = vPuzzleHeight;
    vCanvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
}   
function ChangeImg(){
    var vImgrs = [{src: '1.jpg', title: '1'},{src: '2.jpg', title: '2'},{src: '3.jpg', title: '3'}];
    var rdpos = Math.floor(Math.random() * vImgrs.length);
    vImg.src = vImgrs[rdpos].src;
    vImg.title = vImgrs[rdpos].title;
    document.getElementById('imgTitle').innerHTML = vImg.title;
    document.getElementById('imgView').setAttribute('src', vImg.src);
}
```